# Traversing jsTree tree

Tags: javascript, jstree

Example data:

```
1:A
    2:Aa
    3:Ab
    4:Ac
        5:Aaa
6:B
    7:Ba
    8:Bb
        9:Baa
        10:Bab
```

I'm trying to traverse a jsTree tree and get the path to each item, including parents and roots, so after finishing the traverse, I'd end up having this output:

```
[
    10: ["/6/8/10", "Bab",
    8: ["/6/8", "Bb",
    5: ["/1/4/5", "Aaa"],
    etc...
]
```

How can I do that?

Currently, I have this:

```
$('.jstree-node,.jstree-leaf').each(function(){
    var id   = ($(this).attr('id').split("_"))[0];
    var text = $(this).children('a').text();
    $('#textarea').append(id + " - " + text + "\n");
});
```

which gives me the ID and the text of each item, but

- it feels ugly. My gut is telling me this can be done with jsTree's API
- I'm not sure how to get the path of each item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
$('.jstree-node,.jstree-leaf').each(function(){
    var id   = $(this).attr('id');
    var text = $(this).children('a').text();
    var path = tree.get_path( tree.get_node($(this)), "/", true);
    console.log( (id.split("_"))[0] + " - " + text + " -> (" + path + ")");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `get_json`? See [docs](https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=get_json([obj,%20options]))